# Can DevExpress repositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit support single selection?

Tags: combobox, repository, devexpress, checked

Hi
I am using the repositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit in DevExpress. But I want it only supports single selection not multiple selection it supports by default. Is there any setting property could help on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the CheckedComboBoxEdit works in multiselect mode only.  We suspect that if the end-user wants to select a single item, it is necessary to use the common ComboBoxEdit.